# Richfaces extendedDataTable breaks in ie9

Tags: internet-explorer, jsf-2, richfaces

So I have the following Datatable in a jsf application.

```
     <rich:extendedDataTable border="0px"
                value="#{package.packageSearchList}" var="o" id="mainTable"
                rowClass="test" styleClass="mainTable" rows="5"
                selection="#{package.selection}" selectionMode="single"
                iterationStatusVar="packageIndex">

                <a4j:ajax execute="@firstForm" event="selectionchange"
                    listener="#{package.selectionListener}"
                    render=":secondForm :res" />

                <rich:column>
                    <f:facet name="header" class="header">ID</f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{o.packageID}" />
                </rich:column>

                <rich:column>
                    <f:facet name="header" class="header">Product Name</f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{o.name}" />
                </rich:column>

                <rich:column>
                    <f:facet name="header" class="header">Cost</f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{o.cost}" />
                </rich:column>

                <rich:column>
                    <f:facet name="header" class="header">Duration</f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{o.duration}" />
                </rich:column>
                <rich:column>
                    <f:facet name="header" class="header">Size</f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{o.size}" />
                </rich:column>
                <rich:column headerClass="blank">
                    <a4j:commandButton action="#{package.deletePackage}"
                        render="maintable :firstForm" value="&emsp;Remove"
                        styleClass="fancyButtonRemove">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{package.editedPackage}"
                            value="#{o}" />
                    </a4j:commandButton>
                </rich:column>
            </rich:extendedDataTable>
            <rich:dataScroller id="tableDataScroller" maxPages="2"
                for="mainTable" renderIfSinglePage="true">
            </rich:dataScroller>
```

If a user selects one of these the information contained in the selected object is displayed in an output panel. This works perfectly fine on Chrome, Firefox,IE8 and IE7 however it does not work in IE9 or IE10 and I have no idea why. There is no errors thrown and no exceptions thrown in the backend. It also works in earlier version of IE which has me thouroughly confused.

The strange thing is not everything breaks it. I can select anything in the table and it selects just fine and makes the backend call however it does not render the output panel and when I try to remove a record or use the datascroller to change the extendedDataTable the whole thing breaks. Selection will not work anymore and any buttons lose all responsiveness.

As a workaround I have tried forcing the browser to default to IE8 documents mode using the following code but my IE constantly loads in IE9 regardless of what I do.

```
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

I am using richfaces 4.3.2 Final and Mojarra 2.0. Does anyone have any ideas on what could be happening? Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it turns out that this was related to my Mojarra version, I fixed it by upgrading to version 2.1.9. I needed to overwrite my Javax.faces dependancy with the following in my pom file.

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.9</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.9</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I hope this helps someone else.